# Prevent Host Header Injection / Redirection in Google Kubernetes Engine ( GKE ) Ingress / FrontendConfig

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a k8s deployment which is using **Cloud DNS** And **Managed Certificate ( for SSL )** along with the k8s service.

I have configured HTTP to HTTPS according to [this GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#https_redirect)

Which works perfectly fine and redirects my HTTP requests to HTTPS website.

Now when I am testing the vulnerability for **HOST HEADER INJECTION** using following command from CMD,

```
curl http://staging.mysite.com --header 'Host: malicious.com'
```

I am getting the response like below

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://malicious.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

To mention, my application is built on **angular 11**, and I am using **Nginx** to serve the app after building.

Here's my **Ingress & Frontend Config & Managed Cert Config**

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
    name: ssl-redirect
spec:
    redirectToHttps:
        enabled: true
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: staging-service-ingress
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: staging-global-ip
        networking.gke.io/managed-certificate: staging-cert
        networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: ssl-redirect
spec:
    defaultBackend:
        service:
            name: web-staging-service
            port:
                number: 80
    rules:
        - host: staging.mysite.com
          http:
              paths:
                  -   backend:
                          service:
                              name: web-staging-service
                              port:
                                  number: 80
                      pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                      path: /*
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
    name: staging-cert
spec:
    domains:
        - staging.mysite.com
```

Here's my **Nginx** config

```
worker_processes 4;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        server_tokens off;

        server_name *.mysite.com, mysite.com;

        types {
            module js;
        }

        sendfile on;
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        gzip_min_length   256;
        gzip_vary         on;
        gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level   9;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   404 500 502 503 504  /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    }
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options sameorigin always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Referrer-Policy 'origin';
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "some rules";
    add_header Permissions-Policy "some rules";
}
```

I am not finding any right way to prevent the injection. The application works otherwise perfectly with the current configuration.

Please help me with a proper solution to prevent the HOST HEADER INJECTION

Answer (score 2):

GCP provides protection from these types of attacks via [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor#section-2).  Cloud Armor has built-in [WAF policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning#protocol_attack) which support protection from protocol attacks such as HTTP header injection.

You'll first need to configure your Cloud Armor policy and then you can associate it with a BackendConfig attached to the backend Kubernetes Service ("web-staging-service") used by your Ingress resource.

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: cloud-armor
spec:
  securityPolicy:
    name: "waf-security-policy"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I have configured my Google Cloud Armor policy. and added it with the service / ingress to my GKE. It works perfectly if i make any request like this 
`curl https://staging.mysite.com -H 'Host: malicious.com' -H 'user-agent: Testing'`
I have enabled billing for Managed Protection Plus
If you see, the CURL request is using HTTPS, but if I use HTTP instead then I still get the same response as mentioned in the Question.
Could you please tell me how can I prevent that ?

Comment: Hmm ... I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: hi @garisingh, did you get some time to check ? I still couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the `Host Header Injection` vulnerability caused by the use of the [`redirectToHttps`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#https_redirect) field in the `FrontendConfig` resource by creating a Classic Application Load Balancer via [Config Connector](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/overview) to handle the redirect to the desired host:

**FrontendConfig**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: http-https-redirect-example
  namespace: example-ns
spec:
  sslPolicy: example-ssl-policy
```

**Ingress**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-https-redirect-example
  namespace: example-ns
  labels:
    role: http-https-redirect-example
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: http-https-redirect-example-cert
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: http-https-redirect-example-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: http-https-redirect-example
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "http-https-redirect-example"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: http-https-redirect-example
                port:
                  number: 80
```

The `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http` annotation must be set to `false` so that the LB will be created only for HTTPS.

**ComputeAddress**

```yaml
# https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/compute/computeaddress
apiVersion: compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ComputeAddress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: example-project
  name: http-https-redirect-example
  namespace: example-ns
spec:
  address: 8.8.8.8
  addressType: EXTERNAL
  ipVersion: IPV4
  location: global
  resourceID: http-https-redirect-example
```

We already had a reserved IP address for `http-https-redirect-example` so we needed to include the actual external IP for `spec.address` to avoid conflicts.

**ComputeURLMap**

```yaml
# https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/compute/computeurlmap
apiVersion: compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ComputeURLMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: example-project
  name: http-https-redirect-example
  namespace: example-ns
spec:
  defaultUrlRedirect:
    hostRedirect: example.com
    httpsRedirect: true
    redirectResponseCode: PERMANENT_REDIRECT
    stripQuery: false
  location: global
```

**ComputeTargetHTTPProxy**

```yaml
# https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/compute/computetargethttpproxy
apiVersion: compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ComputeTargetHTTPProxy
metadata:
  name: http-https-redirect-example
  annotations:
    cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: example-project
spec:
  location: global
  urlMapRef:
    name: http-https-redirect-example
```

**ComputeForwardingRule**

```yaml
# https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/compute/computeforwardingrule
apiVersion: compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ComputeForwardingRule
metadata:
  name: http-https-redirect-example
  annotations:
    cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: example-project
spec:
  ipAddress:
    addressRef:
      name: http-https-redirect-example
  ipProtocol: TCP
  loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
  location: global
  portRange: 80-80
  target:
    targetHTTPProxyRef:
      name: http-https-redirect-example
```

Once applied to our GKE cluster the two load balancers were created:
[image: load balancers in GCP console]

We can also verify the vulnerability no longer works:

**Before (using `redirectToHttps`)**:

```bash
$ curl http://example.com -v --header "host: fake.com"
*  Trying 8.8.8.8:80...
* Connected to example.com (8.8.8.8) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: fake.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> 

< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Cache-Control: private
< Location: https://fake.com:443/. <-- vulnerable
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 02:39:55 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

**After:**

```bash
$ curl http://example.com/ -v --header "host: fake.com"                       
*   Trying 8.8.8.8:80...
* Connected to example.com (8.8.8.8) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: fake.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Cache-Control: private
< Location: https://example.com:443/ <-- good response
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 16:21:26 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

---

Additionally GCP Support pointed us to [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264125004) where the following was requested:

> Please include in the backlog the possibility of incorporating the hostRedirect LB feature into GKE Ingress.
>
> As of now, the FrontendConfig of GKE Ingress only supports HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection. We have users who also wish to leverage the hostRedirect feature through the GKE Ingress configuration options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The web application should use the SERVER_NAME instead of the Host header. It should also create a dummy vhost that catches all requests with unrecognized Host headers. This can also be done under Nginx by specifying a non-wildcard SERVER_NAME, and under Apache by using a non-wildcard serverName and turning the UseCanonicalName directive on.
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: You just copied the definition / basic details from another site (https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/host-header-attack/#:~:text=The%20web%20application%20should%20use%20the%20SERVER_NAME%20instead%20of%20the%20Host%20header.&text=This%20can%20also%20be%20done,turning%20the%20UseCanonicalName%20directive%20on)

It doesn't solve the issue at all